# Centrifugal force problem involving pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, angular-velocity

I have this following problem:

[image]

> Two blocks A and B of masses $m_a, m_b$ are placed as shown on a platform at a distance $r$ from the axis of rotation. Find the angular speed of the platform so that the blocks just begin to slide. Consider friction($\mu_s$) between all contact surfaces.

I couldn't decide which block moves outwards and which one inwards, since the masses are incomparable. So I couldn't find appropriate directions of frictional force for each FBD(which includes tension, centrifugal force, normal and friction) as well. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Just pick a direction.  Your answer for angular velocity will not depend on your choice.

Comment: @BillWatts it turns out so! Thank you so much for the help :)